# How to use 2 conditions in one foreach loop

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a script snippet. This gives me an array with 2 propertys: Account and AccessRights. Now I want to build a `foreach` loop, but I also need to store the second value in a variable for further use.

So if I do:

```
foreach ($id in $ACLFile.Account) {
    # do stuff
}
```

I only have the Account property saved in `$id`. But how can I also get its AccessRights value?

```
$ACLFile = GetNTFSAccess | select Account, AccessRights
$ACLGroup = $ACLFile | Group-Object Account
$Singles = $ACLGroup.Where({$_.Count -eq 1}).Group
$Duplicates = $ACLGroup.Where({$_.Count -gt 1})
$ItemizedDuplicates = $Duplicates | foreach {
    [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        "Account"=$_.Group.Account[0];
        "AccessRights" = $_.Group.AccessRights -join ", "
    }
}
@($ItemizedDuplicates, $Singles)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the objects instead of just one property.

```
foreach ($acl in $ACLFile) {
    $id     = $acl.Account
    $access = $acl.AccessRights
    # ...
}
```